# Testing Post Request Using ModelFormSet in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to django and testing, so I'm not sure if there is a more simple solution to this question.

I'm creating an assessment app with a rubric that the user can edit, submit and update.  Each rubric has a preset number of row models that are connected to the rubric model via a foreign key relationship. The user should be able to update multiple row_choice fields in multiple row models and post the row_choice fields to the database.

To portray this in a template, I decided to use a ModelFormSet and iterate over the ModelFormSet in rubric.html.  This works OK, but whenever I try to test this layout using TestCase, I receive the error
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'].  I understand this error because the test does not pass a post request to the view using rubric.html (where ManagementForm is located), but the application works in the browser because the django template renders ManagementForm as html which has no problem in the view.

Can you test a ModelFormSet in django using TestCase, or do you *have* to use LiveServerTestCase and Selenium? Is there a way to get the example test to pass and still test a post request (while using ModelFormSet)? Any help is greatly appreciated.

forms.py

```
class RowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Row
        fields = ['row_choice']

class RubricForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rubric
        fields = ['name']

RowFormSet = modelformset_factory(Row, fields=('row_choice',), extra=0)
```

an example of a failing test:

```
def test_rubric_page_can_take_post_request(self):
    self.add_two_classes_to_semester_add_two_students_to_class_add_one_row()
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.method = "POST"
    response = rubric_page(request, "EG5000", "12345678")

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

and the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python33\assessmenttoolstaging\source\rubricapp\tests\tests.py", line 240, in test_rubric_page_can_take_post_request
    response = rubric_page(request, "EG5000", "12345678")
  File "C:\python33\assessmenttoolstaging\source\rubricapp\views.py", line 52, in rubric_page
    RowFormSetWeb.clean()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 645, in clean
    self.validate_unique()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 651, in validate_unique
    forms_to_delete = self.deleted_forms
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 205, in deleted_forms
    if not self.is_valid() or not self.can_delete:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 304, in is_valid
    self.errors
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 278, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 325, in full_clean
    for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 115, in total_form_count
    return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py", line 97, in management_form
    code='missing_management_form',
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

rubric_page view

```
def rubric_page(request, edclass, studentname):
    edClassSpaceAdded = re.sub('([A-Z]+)', r'\1 ', edclass)
    enrollmentObj = Enrollment.objects.get(edclass__name=edClassSpaceAdded, student__lnumber=studentname)
    rubricForClass = enrollmentObj.keyrubric.get()
    rows = Row.objects.filter(rubric=rubricForClass)
    student = Student.objects.get(lnumber=studentname)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #TestCase cannot test this section of the view
        RowFormSetWeb = RowFormSet(request.POST)
        RowFormSetWeb.clean()
        if RowFormSetWeb.is_valid():
            savedFormset = RowFormSetWeb.save(commit=False)
            for i in savedFormset:
                i.rubric = rubricForClass 
            RowFormSetWeb.save()
            return redirect('/'+ edclass + '/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'rubric.html', {'studentlnumber': student.lnumber,'studentname': student.lastname + ", " + student.firstname, 'RowFormSetWeb':RowFormSetWeb, 'rows':rows, 'edclass':edclass})
    else:
        RowFormSetWeb = RowFormSet(queryset=Row.objects.filter(rubric=rubricForClass))
        return render(request, 'rubric.html', {'studentlnumber': student.lnumber,'studentname': student.lastname + ", " + student.firstname, 'RowFormSetWeb':RowFormSetWeb, 'rows':rows, 'edclass':edclass})
```

form section of rubric.html

```
    <h3 id="rubricheader">TODO Pull model into view</h3>
    <form method="post" action= {% url 'rubricpage' edclass=edclass studentname=studentlnumber %}>

    <table border="1">
<!-- TODO fix this so that it pulls from forms.py -->
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Excellent</th>
            <th>Proficient</th>
            <th>Sub-par</th>
            <th>Abysmal</th>
        </tr>
            {{ RowFormSetWeb.management_form }}
            {% for form in RowFormSetWeb %}
                {{ form.id }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.row_choice }}</td><td>{{ form.excellenttext }}</td><td>{{ form.proficienttext }}</td><td>{{ form.satisfactorytext }}<td>{{ form.unsatisfactorytext }}</td>
            </tr>
            {{ RowFormSetWeb.errors }}
            {% endfor %}

    </table>
    <input name="submitbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="rubricsubmit">
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

from django.db import models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    firstname = models.TextField(default="")    
    lastname = models.TextField(default="")
    lnumber = models.TextField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lnumber
    #TODO add models

class EdClasses(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default='')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through="Enrollment")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Semester(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='201530')
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(EdClasses) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class Rubric(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default="Basic Rubric")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Row(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
    (None, 'Your string for display'),
    ('1','Excellent'),
    ('2','Proficient'),
    ('3','Awful'),
    ('4','The worst ever'),
    )
    rubric = models.ForeignKey(Rubric)
    row_choice = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CHOICES, default="None", blank=True)
    excellenttext = models.TextField(default="")
    proficienttext = models.TextField(default="")
    satisfactorytext = models.TextField(default="")
    unsatisfactorytext = models.TextField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.row_choice


class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    edclass = models.ForeignKey(EdClasses)
    grade = models.TextField(default='') 
    keyrubric = models.ManyToManyField(Rubric)
```

How the form is rendered in the browser:

```
<form action="/201530/EG5000/21743148/" method="post">
<table border="1">
<!-- TODO fix this so that it pulls from forms.py -->
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Excellent</th>
<th>Proficient</th>
<th>Sub-par</th>
<th>Abysmal</th>
</tr>
<input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2"/><input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2"/><input id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0"/><input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000"/>
<input id="id_form-0-id" name="form-0-id" type="hidden" value="3"/>
<tr>
<td><select id="id_form-0-row_choice" name="form-0-row_choice">
<option value="">Your string for display</option>
<option value="1">Excellent</option>
<option value="2">Proficient</option>
<option value="3">Awful</option>
<option value="4">The worst ever</option>
</select></td>
<td>THE BEST!</td>
<td>THE SECOND BEST!</td>
<td>THE THIRD BEST!</td>
<td>YOURE LAST</td>
</tr>
                                        []

                                                <input id="id_form-1-id" name="form-1-id" type="hidden" value="4"/>
<tr>
<td><select id="id_form-1-row_choice" name="form-1-row_choice">
<option value="">Your string for display</option>
<option value="1">Excellent</option>
<option value="2">Proficient</option>
<option value="3">Awful</option>
<option value="4">The worst ever</option>
</select></td>
<td>THE GREATEST!</td>
<td>THE SECOND BEST!</td>
<td>THE THIRD BEST!</td>
<td>YOURE LAST</td>
</tr>
                                        []



                        </table>
<input id="rubricsubmit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" type="hidden" value="0OeU2n0v8ooXHBxdUfi26xxqMIdrA50L"/>
</input></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I've used in the past, albeit not a particularly nice one, is to use the client to get the rendered form, then use something like BeautifulSoup to parse out all the form data from that and update where necessary before posting back. That way you will get all the hidden and prepopulated fields, so you can be sure your tests behave the same way as a user would.

Comment: I was afraid I might have to do something like this.  Do you pass the form data as the data keyword in self.client.post(url, data)?  I am a little confused because, even if I provide self.client.post with a dictionary with the correct data for the form, I still receive the dreaded Management Form error.  Thanks!

Comment: This is what I post to self.client.post.  I added the rendered form to the original post.  I apologize if I'm missing something very basic. `self.client.post("/201530/EG5000/21743148/", {"id_form-0-row_choice":"1", "id_form-1-row_choice":"2"})`

Comment: Well like the error says, you need the values from the management form too; ie the hidden fields like `form-TOTAL_FORMS` etc.

Comment: Thank you!  That gets the test to pass.